# FileWriter output to csv file is blank

Tags: java, csv, filewriter, file-writing

```
FileWriter outfile = new FileWriter("ouput.csv", true); //true = append

        for(int len = 0; len < tempList.size(); len++) {
            LineItem tempItem = tempList.get(len);
            if ( len == 0 ) {
                lastTime = tempItem.getTimeEnd();
                tempItem.setStatus("OK");
                //out
                output( tempItem.toCSV(), outfile);
            } else {
                if ( tempItem.getTimeStart().compareTo(lastTime) <= 0 ) {
                    //WARN
                    if (!tempItem.getStatus().equals("OVERLAP")) {
                        tempItem.setStatus("WARN");
                    }

                } else {
                    //OK
                    //System.out.println( "OK  ;" + tempItem.toCSV());
                    if (!tempItem.getStatus().equals("OVERLAP")) {
                        tempItem.setStatus("OK");
                    }
                }
                // file out write
                output( tempItem.toCSV(), outfile);

                lastTime = tempItem.getTimeEnd();

            }

        }
    }

    private static void output(String line, FileWriter outfile) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(line);

        // Write each line to a new csv file
        outfile.write(line + "\n");

    }
```

Why is my output.csv file 0 kb and empty? But when I print to line I see each string in my console...

Comment: Consider calling `flush()` and `close()` on the `FileWriter` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `output( tempItem.toCSV(), outfile);` please add the below statement. You forgot to `flush`. `Close` automatically `flush` for you.

```
outfile.close();
```

Answer (score 3):

You aren't closing the `FileWriter`.

NB The suggestion to flush as well as close is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

When you `flush(outfile)` it will be written to the file.

When you `close(outfile)` it will be flushed too, automatically. Sometimes you want to `flush()` at other times, but often it's not necessary. You should *always* close files when you've finished with them.

Since Java 7, it's often a good idea to use try-with-resources:

```
try(FileWriter outfile = new FileWriter("output.csv", true)) {
    // code that writes to outfile
}
```

Because `FileWriter` implements `Closeable`, it will call `outfile.close()` automatically when execution leaves this block.